# is it possible to control .net WebBrowser object using Selenium in winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, selenium, webbrowser-control

I am using Selenium driver with real browsers chrome , firefox etceverything works fine, I am wondering if I can use selenium to run tests on the webbrowser Control in a winform project ,  instead of running everything on a real browser i want to run the tests on the WebBrowser Control .

Comment: Can you share your code trials please?

Comment: What is that Selenium can do that you are not able to do via the web browser control itself? You can navigate to pages, fill in fields in forms, trigger click events, send it javascript, etc all from the web browser control.

Comment: @Alexander Ryan Baggett  i am just familiar with selenium , and i think selenium contains some advanced classes that can make life easier , thanks